# Angularjs Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] - what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Well, starting a MEAN project and sure enough I'm getting this common error msg. I've referenced old projects, various Stack Overflow flow questions and other resources out there including AngularJS itself. I still can't see what I'm doing wrong. So here is my code for you.

I do have on my index page both  and in the body with .

I've tried various formats like:

```js
var vidembed = angular.module('vidembed', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial']);
  vidembed.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){....
```

AND

```js
angular.module('vidEmbed', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider){...
```

My head is spinning. Thanks in advance!

App.js:

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name vidEmbed
 * @description
 * # vidEmbed
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular.module('vidEmbed', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider){
   
  $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/movies', {
        templateUrl: 'views/movies.html',
        controller: 'MoviesCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'movies'
      })
      .when('/create/movie', {
        templateUrl: 'views/movie-add.html',
        controller: 'MovieAddCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'movieAdd'
      })
      .when('/movie/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'views/movie-view.html',
        controller: 'MovieViewCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'movieView'
      })
      .when('/movie/:id/delete', {
        templateUrl: 'views/movie-delete.html',
        controller: 'MovieDeleteCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'movieDelete'
      })
      .when('/movie/:id/edit', {
        templateUrl: 'views/movie-edit.html',
        controller: 'MovieEditCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'movieEdit'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      })
    
  .directive('youtube', function(){                                     //embeds video onto page
    return{
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:{
        src:'='
      },
      templateUrl: 'views/youtube.html'
    };
  })
  .filter('trusted', function($sce){                                    //allows for emdeding by allowing trusted certificates
    return function(url){
      return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    };
  })
})
```

Movies.js Controller:

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name clientApp.controller:MoviesCtrl
 * @description
 * # MoviesCtrl
 * Controller of the clientApp
 */
angular.module('vidEmbed')
  .controller('MoviesCtrl', function ($scope, MovieFactory, $location, $routeParams){
    
    MovieFactory.getMovies(function(movies){
     $scope.movies = movies;     
    })
    
  })
```

MovieFactory.js:

```js
var vidembed = angular.module('vidEmbed');
vidEmbed.factory('MovieFactory', ['$http', function($http){
 var factory = {};
 factory.getMovies = function(callback){
  $http({
   method:"GET",
   url:"/movies"
  }).then(function(res){
   callback(res.data);
  }, function(res){
   console.log(res);
  })
 }
 factory.getMovie = function(movieId, callback){
  $http({
   method:"GET",
   url:'/movie/'+movieId
  }).then(function success(res){
   callback(res.data);
  })
 }
 return factory;
}])
```

Comment: What's the rest of the error message?  That'll tell us where the problem lies.

Comment: are you minifying these scripts? because they aren't minification safe as written.

Comment: Ah... sure am. <script src="/assets/angular.min.js"></script> <script src="/assets/angular-route.min.js"></script> I feel like though I at one point  just used the angular library via google and still had the issue. Could have been another project though... what would you suggest? Use just the uncompressed files?

Comment: your `App.js` is missing a closing brace before the `.directive`.  `})` is missing.  Seems to work fine after fixing this, except for the minification issue.  http://plnkr.co/edit/PwrdeUEheSBj64j4hwpk?p=preview.  Of course, that's barring the other controllers not declared in this code and such.....

Comment: @LANole - using the angular minified scripts aren't a problem.  Claies was asking if you are minifying your script files.

Comment: Thank you so much! Error msg is now gone. Just need to fix the new one of: Uncaught ReferenceError: vidEmbed is not defined
    at http://localhost:8000/Factories/MovieFactory.js:2:1

Comment: because you defined `var vidembed....` and then on the next line tried to use `vidEmbed` (note the `E`).

Comment: Ah yes... capitals. so picky. Thanks @Claies. and thanks @jbrown! Will need to read up on minifying script files. So much to learn.